# grid-template-areas Valor de la propiedad invalido

Tags: html, css

¿Porque no me hace caso el `grid-template-areas` en el navegador? Me mete todo los `div` hijos dentro del `div` padre.

Codigo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;   
  grid-template-areas:
    'titulo titulo titulo titulo titulo'
    'articulo1 articulo1 articulo2 articulo3 articulo4'
    'articulo1 articulo1 articulo5 articulo6';
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-gap:30px;    
}
    
.titulo {       
  grid-area: titulo;
}
.articulo1 { grid-area: articulo1; } 
.articulo2 { grid-area: articulo2; } 
.articulo3 { grid-area: articulo3; } 
.articulo4 { grid-area: articulo4; } 
.articulo5 { grid-area: articulo5; } 
.articulo6 { grid-area: articulo6; }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="titulo">Articulos destacados</div>
        <div class="articulo1"></div>
        <div class="articulo2"></div>
        <div class="articulo3"></div>  
        <div class="articulo4"></div>
        <div class="articulo5"></div>
        <div class="articulo6"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: .articulo1 {
       grid-area: articulo1;       
    }
  .articulo2 {
       grid-area: articulo2;
     }
  .articulo3 { 
      grid-area: articulo3;
     }
  .articulo4 { 
      grid-area: articulo4;
     }
  .articulo5 {
       grid-area: articulo5;
     }
  .articulo6 {
       grid-area: 
       articulo6; 
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la definición de las áreas, en las primeras 2 filas has definido 5 columnas y en la tercera fila has definido solo 4 columnas. Todas las filas deben tener el mismo número de colunmas.

Solucionando eso, tu codigo quedaria asi:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;    
  grid-template-areas:
    'titulo titulo titulo titulo titulo'
    'articulo1 articulo1 articulo2 articulo3 articulo4'
    'articulo1 articulo1 articulo2 articulo5 articulo6';
  background-color: aqua;
  grid-gap:30px;    
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

.titulo {
  grid-area: titulo;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
.articulo1 {
  grid-area: articulo1;
  background-color: #8ca0ff;
}

.articulo2 {
  grid-area: articulo2;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}
.articulo3 {
  grid-area: articulo3;
  background-color: #ffff64;
}
.articulo4 {
  grid-area: articulo4;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
.articulo5 {
  grid-area: articulo5;
  background-color: #8cffa0;
}
.articulo6 {
  grid-area: articulo6;
  background-color: #ffa08c;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="titulo">Articulos destacados</div>
    <div class="articulo1"></div>
    <div class="articulo2"></div>
    <div class="articulo3"></div>  
    <div class="articulo4"></div>
    <div class="articulo5"></div>
    <div class="articulo6"></div>
</div>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.